Minimum number of unions to make collection of subsets
Given a set $S$ with $n$ elements, I want to know the minimum number of unions I need, starting from singletons, to make every subset of size $(n-1)$, allowing reuse of intermediate unions.
For example, let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  Then I want to make all of the subsets of size 3.  Obviously the worst approach is to take unions of the required singletons for each subset - in this case that would be 2 unions x 4 sets = 8 unions.  But allowing reuse lowers this: I could first use 1 union to form the set $\{1, 2 \}$ and then use one union each to make $\{1, 2, 3 \}$ and $\{1, 2, 4 \}$.  Repeating this with $\{3, 4 \}$ lowers the total number of unions needed to 6.
(Updated in light of answer below) I have done some numerical experiments that suggest the optimum for a set $S$ of size $n$ is $3n - 6$.  This is mysterious to me, though I guess it must have some nice combinatorial interpretation (it is also the same as the number of edges in a maximal planar graph...)

For $n=5$, your original conjectured formula yields $10$, but the minimum is instead $9$, attained by using the following intermediate sets:
$$\{1,2\},\{4,5\},\{1,2,3\},\{3,4,5\}$$

For fixed $n$, you can solve the problem via integer linear programing as follows.  For $S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$, let binary decision variable $x_S$ indicate whether subset $S$ is selected.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_S x_S - n$$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_S &= 1 &&\text{for $S$ such that $|S|\in\{1,n-1\}$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_{T,U: T \cup U = S} x_T x_U &\ge x_S &&\text{for $S$ such that $1<|S|<n$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} forces each singleton $\{i\}$ and each $(n-1)$-subset to be selected.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the logical implication $$x_S \implies \bigvee_{T,U: T \cup U = S} (x_T \land x_U)$$
You can linearize the quadratic constraint \eqref{2} by introducing binary (or just nonnegative) decision variables $y_{T,U}$ and replacing \eqref{2} with
\begin{align}
\sum_{T,U: T \cup U = S} y_{T,U} &\ge x_S &&\text{for $S$ such that $|S|>1$} \tag3\label3 \\
y_{T,U} &\le x_T &&\text{for $T,U \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag4\label4 \\
y_{T,U} &\le x_U &&\text{for $T,U \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag5\label5
\end{align}

it appears 3n-6 is correct.

Your new linear conjecture is correct at least for $n\le7$.

Can I ask how you are checking this?  I am only succeeding using an algorithm I wrote which I can't prove optimality for.

I used integer linear programming, with a binary decision variable for each subset and for each pair of subsets.

could you post the objective function/constraints you used?
